# I want the value from my array if it does not appear in another array

Tags: php, arrays

How can i get the desired output? I want to check if array1 "entry_id" is not the same as array2 "entry_id"

How can i do that? I tried with array_diff_key .. But it did not work

Array1

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_id] => 53242 [site_id] => 2 [channel_id] => 2 [author_id] => 5 [1] => Array ( [entry_id] => 76435 [site_id] => 8 [channel_id] => 8 [author_id] => 9
```

Array2

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_id] => 89764 [site_id] => 1 [channel_id] => 1 [author_id] => 5  [1] => Array ( [entry_id] => 53242[site_id] => 7 [channel_id] => 9 [author_id] => 1
```

I would like to compare array1 and array2 with each other and get the desired output:

Desired output:

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_id] => 76434 [site_id] => 8 [channel_id] => 8 [author_id] => 9 [1] => Array ( [entry_id] => 76435 [site_id] => 8 [channel_id] => 8 [author_id] => 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For smallish size of input arrays you can basically do it the long way using two for loops.

Sample code (not tested!):

```
// $array1 and $array2 are the inputs
// $array3 is output
$array3=array();
// Keep track of what we have already found
$buff=array();
foreach($array1 as $a1){
    foreach($array2 as $a2){
        // Check for matching ids and is not already used
        if($a1['entry_id']==$a2['entry_id'] and !isset($buff[$a1['entry_id']])){
            $array3[]=$a1;
            $buff[$a1['entry_id']]=1;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array3); // Debug
```

**EDIT:** OP wanted the opposite, so...

Sample code (tested!):

```
// 2 pass filter
// $array1 and $array2 are the inputs
$array1=array(
    array('entry_id'=>1,'t'=>"a1"),
    array('entry_id'=>2,'t'=>"b1"),
    array('entry_id'=>3,'t'=>"c1"),
);
$array2=array(
    array('entry_id'=>1,'t'=>"a2"),
    array('entry_id'=>2,'t'=>"b2"),
    array('entry_id'=>4,'t'=>"d2"),
);

// $array3 is output
$array3=array();
// Keep track of what we have already found
$buff=array();

foreach($array1 as $a1) $buff[$a1['entry_id']]=array(1,$a1);

foreach($array2 as $a2){
    if(isset($buff[$a2['entry_id']])){
            $buff[$a2['entry_id']]=array(2,$a2);
    }else{
            $buff[$a2['entry_id']]=array(1,$a2);
    }
}

foreach($buff as $k=>$v) if($v[0]==1) $array3[]=$v[1];

print_r($array3); // Debug
```

Comment: My array is not small, I have just removed all unnecessary material from it.

Comment: I am sorry I wrote wrong. I thought the opposite. I just updated it. Still hope you will help.

Comment: Is the code working? If not, you'll need to give a sample of the 2 arrays so we can test it out.

Comment: Alright! Just +1 my answer and accept it as a correct answer!

Comment: your code works if you want the value that is common to both arrays. But it does not work for the opposite. I want the value that does not fit into the picture.

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to include a few lines of sample data for array1 and array2 in CODE form - otherwise its hard for everyone.

Comment: I just made your code work, but it is not working as its purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$arreglo1 = Array (
        Array (
            "entry_id" => 53242,
            "site_id" => 2,
            "channel_id" => 2,
            "author_id" => 1
        ),
        Array (
            "entry_id" => 76435,
            "site_id" => 8,
            "channel_id" => 8,
            "author_id" => 9,
        )
    );

    $arreglo2 = Array (
        Array (
            "entry_id" => 89764, 
            "site_id" => 1,
            "channel_id" => 1,
            "author_id" => 5
        ),
        Array (
            "entry_id" => 53242,
            "site_id" => 7,
            "channel_id" => 9,
            "author_id" => 1
            )
        );

     $cnt = 0;
     foreach($arreglo1 as $arr1) {
      foreach($arreglo2 as $arr2){
       if ($arr1["entry_id"] == $arr2["entry_id"]) {
         $agregarlo = FALSE;
         break;
       }
       else {
        $agregarlo = TRUE;
       } 
      }

      if ($agregarlo) {
       $resultado[$cnt] = $arr1;
      }
      $cnt++;
     }

     var_dump($resultado);
    ?>
```

Wich give you this:

```
array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { ["entry_id"]=> int(76435) ["site_id"]=> int(8) ["channel_id"]=> int(8) ["author_id"]=> int(9) } }
```